# JPA force enum converter on specific query (where clause)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, enums, hibernate-mapping

I've an enum field that IS NOT STORED in the database, but is used on the where clause of a complex query I've

this is the query:

```
"SELECT t FROM Task t " +
                   "WHERE " +
 "(:status is null OR GetTaskStatus(t.dueDate, t.completedDate) = :status) " )
   @Convert(converter = TaskStatus.Converter.class,attributeName = "status")
   public Page<Task> findAll(
            @Param("status") TaskStatus status,
           Pageable pageable
   );
```

TaskStatus is an enum

```
public enum TaskStatus {
   COMPLETED(2), LATE_COMPLETE(14), SCHEDULED(3), DUE_TODAY(5), LATE(7), OTHER(11);

   private final int code;

   TaskStatus(int i) {
      code = i;
   }

   @javax.persistence.Converter(autoApply = true)
   public static final class Converter implements AttributeConverter<TaskStatus, Integer> {

      @Override
      public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(TaskStatus attribute) {
         if (attribute == null)
            return null;

         return attribute.code;
      }

      @Override
      public TaskStatus convertToEntityAttribute(Integer dbData) {
         return fromInteger(dbData);
      }

      public static TaskStatus fromInteger(Integer dbData) {
         return dbData == null || dbData == 0 ? null : Arrays.stream(values()).filter(taskStatus -> taskStatus.code == dbData).findFirst().orElse(OTHER);
      }
   }

}
```

As you can see i've aconverter for my enum and i'm trying for force firebase to use it

this enum is not persisted into any table in the database but is calculated at runtime according to the due_date and completed_date with a custom function that i created [the function is working 100% tested if i run this query into the mysql with the real enum values it works fine]

the problem is that when mapping the params to values for the query, hibernate maps the status AS STRING, and the GetTaskStatus returns and INT...

I dont want to change the GetTaskStatus function, how can i force hibernate to map status to int for this query?

Comment: Why don't you pass the enum id as parameter instead of the whole enum?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work?

```
   @Query("...") // Same query
   public Page<Task> findAll(@Param("status") Integer status, Pageable pageable);
```

and

```
Integer status = taskStatus != null ? taskStatus.code() : null;
Page<Task> page = repo.findAll(status,... );
```

or

```
Integer status = new Converter().convertToDatabaseColumn(taskStatus);
```

The `@Converter` annotation is for mapping entity attributes. I don't think it supposed to be used for mapping query parameters.

Comment: this works but is ugly code... if am able to map a column field i should be able to map a query param otherwise how would i query? probably there is something on hibernate which i dont know for doing this....

Comment: I don't think there is. But you can actually use the converter: `Integer status = new Converter().convertToDatabaseColumn(taskStatus)`. You can actually refactor this code in many different way. The point is that parameters are not bound to an entity, so I don't think HIbernate apply any transformation to them